# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /:

Tags: python, generator

I have "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: " for this code

```
class Foo(object):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return print("add")
    def __div__(self, other):
        return print("div")


Foo() + Foo()
add
```

** BUT for /  **

```
Foo() / Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-104-8efbe0dde481>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo() / Foo()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Foo' and 'Foo'
```

Comment: Please format your code properly next time.

Comment: `+` also works for strings as in `"wor" + "ks!" = "works!"`. The `/`openand does not.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis. For the same reason that this fails. So relevant to the problem but not the solution.

Comment: In python3, `__div__` is replaced by `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__`.

Answer (score 20):

Python3 uses special division names: `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__` for the `/` and `//` operators, respectively.

In Python3, the `/` is a true division in that `5/2` will return the floating point number `2.5`. Similarly `5//2` is a *floor* division or *integer* division because it will always return an int, in this case `2`.

In Python2 the `/` operator worked the same way that the `//` operator works in Python3. Because of the way that the operators changed between versions, the `__div__` name was removed to to avoid ambiguity.

Reference: http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html#acts-like-number

Comment: For completeness, , `__floordiv__` is also the special method for `//` in Python 2.  `__truediv__` can be used in Python 2 with `from __future__ import division`.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you can use **truediv**:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return print("add")
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return print("div")
```

Comment: Some explanation please.